# Django 1.9 with cache in Redis

Tags: django, caching, redis, django-redis

I have a application on Django 1.8.8 with cache based on [django-redis](https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis). And I want to update to Django 1.9.2. But [django-redis not working with Django >= 1.9](http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_requirements).

[django-redis-cache](https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache) also not working with Django 1.9 (for me). And I not found requirements in the documentation of django-redis-cache.

Have anyone any experience with cache in Redis with Django 1.9+? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that django-redis does definitely not support 1.9, or have they just not updated the documentation to say that they do?

Comment: Now I see that django-redis is working with Django 1.9 with cache configuration as that of Forge. Earlier, my configuration is not an element named "OPTIONS".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using [`Django 1.9`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/) and [`django-redis`](http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/) version `4.3`, I've set my cache to use `RedisCache`:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}
```

Follow the tutorial [here](http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_configure_as_cache_backend).

And set values in my `cache`:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set("foo", "value", timeout=100)
```

I was able to access those values on `redis` using `redis-cli`, so I guess it's seems to be working.